# Fill DropDownList from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net, drop-down-menu

I am new to C# and trying to populate a DropDownList  based on a database value.  I tried connecting to database as shown below - tested with the statement and it says connected. Can I assume this is correct? Am I on the right track?  Also, how do I then select value from the table and fill DropDownList  with a field?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection (
    "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:customers.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");

     try
     {
         connection.Open();
         TextBox1.Text = "connected";
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
         TextBox1.Text = " not connected";
     }
 }
```

Comment: ive now figured this out sorry for wasting anyones time :)

Comment: You are on the right track. To add items to a combobox, just `comboBox1.Items.Add(object)`

Comment: @Ken: Can you click **delete** on this question because you don't need answers so it will end up in low quality without relevant answers.

Comment: Since your hardcoding SQL into your code behind, you might as well use a SqlDataSource control. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dz12d98w(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection (
    "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:customers.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");

     try
     {
          SqlDataReader dReader;
          SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
          cmd.Connection = connection;
          cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
          cmd.CommandText ="Select distinct [Name] from [Names]" +
          " order by [Name] asc";
         connection.Open();

         dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
         if (dReader.HasRows == true)
         {
              while (dReader.Read())
              //Names collection is a combo box.
              namesCollection.Add(dReader["Name"].ToString());

         }
         else
         {
              MessageBox.Show("Data not found");
         }
           dReader.Close()
         TextBox1.Text = "connected";
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
         TextBox1.Text = " not connected";
     }
 }

Hope that helps................
```

Answer (score 0):

It's So Much Simple :----

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(); 
DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=TOP7\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=t1;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Test;Password=t123";
string query = "Select * from tbl_User"; 
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con); 
cmd.CommandText = query;
con.Open(); 
SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
adpt.Fill(ds);
comboBox1.Items.Clear();
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "UserName";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "UserId";
comboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = NIPOON; Initial Catalog = CustomerOrders; Integrated Security = true"))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name FROM Customer", con);
                con.Open();

                dropDownList.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                dropDownList.DataTextField = "Name";
                dropDownList.DataValueField = "Name";
                dropDownList.DataBind();
            }
```